# Install Network printer

Tags: drivers, package-management, printing, debian

I have a Xerox Versalinkc600 network printer and Xerox Debian package printer driver installer, which I have downloaded. How do I (step by step) install the printer driver?

Comment: Install this deb using `dpkg`.

Comment: Double clicking on the `deb` file in `Nautilus` should open it in **Ubuntu Software**. There you should be able to see an *Install* button.

Answer (score 0):

You can install local DEB packages using the `dpkg` tool, and you do so by running the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <packagename>.deb
```

Make sure to replace `<packagename>` with the actual name of the package.

There is also a chance you may get dependency errors the first time you run this. If so, run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, and then re-run the `dpkg` command and the package will install fine.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, This worked great. Now, How do I install the printer in cups?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, then go to Settings -> Printers and set everything there.